# Получить данные после отправки основного запроса в python

Tags: python, requests, aiohttp

Есть сайт `https://ts-music.com/`, если попробовать найти музыку в поиске вверху сайта, к примеру "Моргенштерн", на сайте отобразится музыка согласно запросу человека, также на этом сайте есть ( результаты поиска с вконтакте ), если перейти по Результатам с вк, также загрузится музыка на сайте, но двумя разными запросами.
Мне необходимо получить данные с api после обращения к основному запросу, как это можно сделать?

Если кому-то вообще не понятно, перейдите в пк по ссылке `ttps://ts-music.com/search/м/vk/` и зайдите в инструменты разработчика, вкладку Сеть, обновите страницу F5 и увидите несколько запросов, первый запрос основной - который загружает второй, а благодаря второму запросу загружается необходимая мне информация о списке треков на сайт.

Я не знаю, что необходимо сделать или написать, чтобы получить нужные мне данные, может быть необходимо как-то подождать полной загрузки страницы и после этого пытаться что-то получить, буду рад любому ответу, Спасибо.

В случае если я попытаюсь вывести данные, получу:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="b_search_info">
<div class="b_tabs" id="tabs_search">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="/search/w/"> Результаты с сайта</a>
</li>
<li style="padding-bottom: 6px; border-bottom: 2px solid; border-color: #da0f47; ">
<a href="/search/w/vk/">Показать результаты с вк</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="vk_search">
<img src="https://i-tsmusic.com/i/img/ajax-loader.gif" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"/>
</div>
<script>

            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("vk_search").innerHTML =
                        this.responseText;
                    Inline.add('main', function () {
                        Mp3.Likes.create();
                    });
                    Inline.add('main', function () {
                        Mp3.ListMp3s.create();
                    });
                    Inline.exec('main');
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "https://api-vk.com/tunes-music-vk-search.php?q=w&i=0&hash=97a68069320ad38be78cc56adf4ad7a4", true);
            xhttp.send();


    </script>
</div>
</div>
```

```
# Код которым хочу получить хотя бы какие-то данные о наличии музыки на сайте

async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post('https://ts-music.com/search/м/vk/') as response:
                html_code = BS(await response.text(), 'lxml')
                print(html_code)
```

Скриншоты:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Библиотека `requests` сама по себе не умеет выполнять javascript, а тут содержимое подгружается именно javascript-ом.

Варианты как решить:

- [оберткой](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/) над requests, которая умеет javascript
- [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) - это вариант медленней, так как он запускает реальный браузер (это можно делать в фоне), но совместимость будет лучше.
- вручную выполнить тот запрос, который в javascript выполняется. Этот вариант более хрупкий, так как логика страницы может поменяться в любой момент и придется с ней менять и логику программы.