# Не правильно кодирует код сайта при парсинге , что делать?

Tags: python, парсер, веб-сайт

Всем доброго дня суток. Пытаюсь парсить сайт , но когда я пытаюсь скопировать код сайта на питоне на свой компьютер в html формате или просто в cmd , вместо кода выходит полный бред.

Пример кода:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://auto.ru/moskva/cars/subaru/new/'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0' , 'accept': '*/*'}   
r = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
src = r.content

with open("index.html", "wb", encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
            file.write(src)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вывод:h627GkIVMWCoPHP0pAQ==">(()=>{var e={1716:e=>{e.exports=function(e,t){let r,n,o=!1;return function i(){if(o)return r=arguments,void(n=t

Comment: Поместите код в сам вопрос. Вы можете редактировать свой вопрос. А комментарии потом удалите.

Comment: Ну, я вижу кусок яваскрипта. Попробуйте брать не `r.text`, а `r.content` и записывать его в файл в бинарном формате `"wb"`, может понятнее станет что-то.

Comment: Сайт формируется с помощью JavaScript, такое бывает. Что вы конкретно хотите от этого сайта?

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет , но не помогло. Добавил код с вашим советом , но вывод одинаковый , что и был раньше , фрагменты вывода я тоже добавил!

Comment: Я хотел сделать список из машин и их стоимости . Брать информацию с сайта

Comment: У вас содержимое не записалось - параметр `encoding` не совместим с двоичной записью файла `"wb"`, нужно `encoding` убрать. В любом случае там JS внутри. Можно попробовать использовать `Selenium`, но может и не помочь.

Comment: Как думаете , стоит попробовать другой сайт , так как в документации которой я смотрел и видео , все было на много проще ахахах

Comment: Я убирал encoding

Comment: Сайт генерируется динамически. Одного `requests` с `BeautifulSoup` недостаточно. Нужно выполнять javascript. Смотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1291875/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-python/1291935#1291935 так что, если вы делаете, чтоб попробовать и разобраться, то стоит начать с более простого сайта.