# Чтение данных с сайта, появляющихся не сразу

Tags: python

Имеется такой код:

```
response = requests.post("https://mysite.ru/index", data=body timeout=(3, 15))
```

Этот запрос выполняется с 200 статусом и на выходе получаю сайт с каркасом таблицы, но пустыми ячейками. Когда захожу на сайт и перехожу на ссылку, которая должна отобразить таблицу запускается аякс скрипт. Появляется значок ожидания и секунд через 10-15 появляется сама таблица со значениями. Во вкладке network запрос отправляется один раз, когда была нажата кнопка для формирования таблицы. Через 10 секунд, когда данные появились никакого запроса не отобразилось. Я так понимаю данные передались через веб сокет или какой то ява скрипт. Куда двигаться, в каком направлении, что бы можно было отловить эти данные

Comment: «в каком направлении» — в направлении той же самой вкладки network, все вебсокеты она тоже обязательно отобразит

Comment: кроме запроса после нажатия никаких запросов не появляется

Comment: Ну значит открывайте исходный код этого аякс-скрипта и изучайте, что он на самом деле делает после нажатия

Comment: а можно как нибудь по запросу получить эту страницу, не останавливая выполнение скриптов, следить за определенным тегом (`<div id="necessaryTag"></div>`) и когда он станет не пустым считать данные

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получить данные после отправки основного запроса в python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1291875/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-python)

Comment: @RomanKonoval прочитал описание селениума, звучит как то, что надо, отпишусь после тестов, спасибо большое!